# How do I implement collision detection with a sprite walking up a rocky-terrain hill?

Tags: collision-detection, sdl

I'm working in SDL and have bounding rectangles for collisions set up for each frame of the sprite's animation. However, I recently stumbled upon the issue of putting together collisions for characters walking up and down hills/slopes with irregularly curved or rocky terrain - what's a good way to do collisions for that type of situation? Per-pixel? Loading up the points of the incline and doing player-line collision checking? Should I use bounding rectangles in general or circle collision detection?

Comment: What is your problem specifically? Is it the collision detection or response? Try to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this guide [Implementing Slopes](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/)

It is quite detailed and even though I haven't programmed slopes yet it has a lot of useful information and tell you not only ways of doing it, but you'll also find out how they were made on games you know well, so that's always a plus :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply real physics, you have to use physical engine. You can make your own physical engine but it implies a huge physical and programming knowledge. I would recommend you to use [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) which is a good 2D physical engine written in C++. There are lot of tutorials about Box2D from which you can learn it easy and quickly. [Here](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) is also the official manual for it.